# Rails does not save reference ID to record error: "Class must exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

Issue is I can't find why reference column id can't be inserted when create new record.

I have 3 table shop_plan, shop and app

Below is tables schema:

```
  create_table "shop_plans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "url"
    t.bigint "plan_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["plan_id"], name: "index_shops_on_plan_id"
  end

  create_table "apps", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "shop_id"
    t.binint "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["app_id"], name: "index_apps_on_shop_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "shops", "shop_plans", column: "plan_id"
  add_foreign_key "apps", "shops"
```

And below is Model

```
class ShopPlan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shop
end

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop_plan, class_name: 'ShopPlan', foreign_key: :plan_id
  has_many :app
end

class App < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop, class_name: 'Shop', foreign_key: :shop_id
end
```

There will be 1 default record added in seed.db for table shop_plan

```
ShopPlan.create(name: 'Basic')
```

**ShopPlan** and **Shop** are linked by `plan_id` column in `Shop`

**Shop** and **App** are linked by `shop_id` column in `App`

I pre-insert some value when user access index:

```
#basic_plan
@basicPlan = ShopPlan.where(name: "Basic").first

# if new shop registered, add to database
unless Shop.where(url: @shop_session.url).any?
  shop = Shop.new
  shop.url = @shop_session.url
  shop.plan_id = @basicPlan.id

  shop.save
end
```

This insert works well, however, when i run 2nd insert:

```
@shop= Shop.where(url: @shop_session.url).first
    unless App.where(shop_id: @shop.id).any?
      app = App.new
      app.shop_id = @shop.id,
      app.amount = 10
      app.save
    end
```

error occurs as somehow `app.shop_id` will not add in my `@shop.id` and it will return will error: `{"shop":["must exist"]}`

I even try hard-code `app.shop_id =1` but it does not help and when I add in `optional: true` to app.db model, it will insert `null`

Appreciate if anyone can help point out why I get this error

**EDIT**: @arieljuod to be clear
1) I have to specific exact column class due to between `Shop` And `Shop_Plan`, i'm using a manual `plan_id` instead of using default `shopplans_id` columns.
2) I have update 1 column inside App and all that unless is just to do checking when debugging.

Comment: What happens when you pluralize your has_many associations, so `has_many :shops` and `has_many :apps`?

Comment: @David It still return same result, but just to mention my insertion for `Shop` works well, issue only occurs at `App` insertion. thankyou anyway

Comment: In order for this to work properly need to change the association in ShopPlan to `has_many :shops, foreign_key: :plan_id`. Otherwise rails won't be able to properly join the association from this end. You can also change the association in App to just `belongs_to :shop` and `belongs_to :shop_plan, foreign_key: :plan_id`. The `class_name` and `foreign_key` options are only needed when they cannot be deduced from the name of the association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the silly reason why my code does not work.
It's not because `as_many :shops` and `has_many :app` and also not because my code  when creating the record.

It just due to silly comma ',' when creating new record in App at `app.shop_id = @shop.id,`, as I was keep switching between Ruby and JavaScript. Thank you @arieljuod and @David for your effort

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like @David pointed out, your associations names are not right. You have to set `has_many :shops` and `has_many :apps` so activerecord knows how to find the correct classes.

Second, you don't have to specify the `class_name` option if the class can be infered from the association name, so it can be `belongs_to :shop` and `belongs_to :shop_plan, foreign_key: :plan_id`. It works just fine with your setup, it's just a suggestion to remove unnecesary code.

Now, for your relationships, I think you shouldn't do those `first` `any?` `new` block manually, rails can handle those for you.

you could do something like

```
@basicPlan = ShopPlan.find_by(name: "Basic")

#this gives you the first record or creates a new one
@shop = @basicPlan.shops.where(url: @shop_session.url).first_or_create 

#this will return the "app" of the shop if it already exists, and, if nil, it will create a new one
@app = @shop.app or @shop.create_app
```

Comment: Thank you, let me edit my question, actually app will contains some other columns, but due to sensitive value, I can't list down all here

Comment: @Jacky, the `create_app` method accepts a hash with attributes https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to